# uncaught TypeError with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to javascript and I've been trying to develop something to assist me in teaching my class about binary encoders and decoders. This is the code that I've come up with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pressme').click(function(){

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
if(randomnumber == 0){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 1){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 2){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 3){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 4){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 5){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 6){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
}
if(randomnumber == 7){
    $('#i_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
    $('#i_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');

    $('#o_0').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_1').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_2').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_3').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_4').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_5').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_6').removeClass.addClass('wire_inactive');
    $('#o_7').removeClass.addClass('wire_active');
}
});
});
</script>
```

The goal is to switch the class of the input wires(labelled as i_0 to i_3) and output wires(labelled as o_0 to o_7 ) according to the number generated by the random number generator. However, when I click on the button(whose id I've set as pressme), I get uncaught TypeErrors. Can anyone please point me in the right direction in solving this?

Comment: Just as a quick aside, you can group selectors using a comma, like this: `$('#i_1, #i_2, ... #o_6, #o_7).doStuff()`.

Comment: Please post the exact type error you get from your browser's console.

Comment: You can't do `.removeClass.addClass()`. `removeClass`is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeClass` doesn't have a member named `addClass`, so you can't write `removeClass.addClass('')`. `removeClass` is a function, and you have to invoke it:

```
$('#o_7').removeClass('wire_inactive').addClass('wire_active');
```

You can reduce all of your code to

```
// inactivate all
$('#o_0, #o_1, #o_2, #o_3, #o_4, #o_5, #o_6, #o_7').removeClass('wire_active').addClass('wire_inactive');

// activate random item
$('#o_' + randomnumber).removeClass('wire_inactive').addClass('wire_active');
```

... and apply similar logic for the `i_` items; I'm not sure what your logic between toggling them on and off is...

Comment: Instead of manually typing it all in, a simple loop will suffice.

Comment: Thanks David! That solved the issue. The purpose is to create a little page on the school website where students can play around to see how a binary decoder works

Comment: @Zirak: a loop would certainly work, and something like `$("*[id^='o_']")` would probably do the trick as well. If I could change the markup, I'd probably just use a common class name.